# Defining bitfields according to endianness at compile time

Tags: c++, endianness

Lets say I have the following 2 structures based upon 2 bytes:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct Foo {
    unsigned short a : 5;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short d : 5;
} ;

struct Bar {
    unsigned short a : 5;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short d : 3;
    unsigned short e : 2;
} ;
```

And I have a union which containes them:

```
union Baz {
    unsigned short val;
    struct Foo foo;
    struct Bar bar;
} ;
```

And then in my program I can put a value using val, and get a, b, c, d and e values according to the their bitfields, no bitwise operations/interfaces and more required.

The problem though, is that I need it to support both big and little endianness, which means that I need to have my struct define the bitfields according to the endianness at compile time.

Thus, I need something like this:

```
#pragma pack(1)
#if BIG_ENDIAN
struct Foo {
    unsigned short a : 5;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short d : 5;
} ;

struct Bar {
    unsigned short a : 5;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short d : 3;
    unsigned short e : 2;
} ;

#else
struct Foo {
    unsigned short d : 5;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short a : 5;
} ;

struct Bar {
    unsigned short e : 2;
    unsigned short d : 3;
    unsigned short c : 2;
    unsigned short b : 4;
    unsigned short a : 5;
} ;
#endif
```

I tried looking this up and all I could find is either a runtime check or compiled values which can only be used at runtime.
I know that there are many macros like BYTE_ORDER, LITTLE_ORDER, BIG_ORDER and more, but I cannot ensure they will be defined in the requested deployed environment, as well as the endian.h header files. Also, as far as I know, boost's endian.hpp is implementing what i stated above regarding the macros, so I am not certain it will make any difference..

Any suggestions?

---

edit1:
In reply to one of the comments: I need a c++03 solution, but a c++11/14 one would also be nice for enlightenment.

Comment: Just avoid bit-fields and shift bits accordingly (although, they are nice for debugging)

Comment: With a citation of boost, probably best to choose just `c++` tag.

Comment: You do know that writing to one element of the union and reading from another is undefined behaviour?

Comment: I currently try to stir sth up with a wrapper for std::bitset and a FooView(wrapper).a instead of wrapper.Foo.a. But issue is, if it's not just qnd hack it's almost almost TLDR,  because it needs plenty of traits and SFINAE to get some industrial strength. Anyway - @Gulzar - "C++" means up to C++14 here?

Answer (score 1):

The question is too long for a simple short question: 'How do I know endiannes during compile time.', and regretfully, the answer to this question is 'You can not'.

The thing is, neither Posix, nor C/C++ standard specify anything in regards to endianness. The only thing you can do is to test for known architecture-specific macros and derive enddiannes from it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, one can stir up sth  with [**`std::bitset`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

It is, however, a little lengthy.

*I could not yet test that on a big-endian machine, thus if someone has such at her/his disposal and finds a bug, I'd appreciate a message.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <endian.h>

using std::size_t;

struct BE {};
struct LE {};

#if __BYTE_ORDER  ==  __BIG_ENDIAN
using PE = BE;
#else
using PE = LE;
#endif

template<typename> struct BitTraits{};

template<> struct BitTraits<uint8_t> {
    constexpr static size_t numbits = 8;
};

template<> struct BitTraits<uint16_t> {
    constexpr static size_t numbits = 16;
};

template<typename T>
class BitField {
public:
    using assignment_type = T;
    using container_type = 
        typename std::bitset<BitTraits<T>::numbits>;

    inline BitField(assignment_type data) : data_(data) {}

    inline BitField& operator=(assignment_type data) {
        data_ = data;
        return *this;
    }

    inline container_type& data() {
        return data_;
    } 

    inline unsigned long long to_ullong() const {
        return data_.to_ullong();
    }

private:    
    container_type data_;
};

template<size_t, typename Endianness = PE> struct BitSliceTraits;

template<size_t length> 
struct BitSliceTraits<
    length, 
    typename std::enable_if<1<=length && length<=8, PE>::type
> { 
    using assignment_type = uint8_t; 

    inline static assignment_type little_endian(assignment_type b) {
        return b;
    }
};

template<size_t length> 
struct BitSliceTraits<
    length, 
    typename std::enable_if<9<=length && length<=16, LE>::type
> { 
    using assignment_type = uint16_t; 

    inline static assignment_type little_endian(assignment_type b) {
        return b;
    }
};

template<size_t length> 
struct BitSliceTraits<
    length, 
    typename std::enable_if<9<=length && length<=16, BE>::type
> { 
    using assignment_type = uint16_t; 

    inline static assignment_type little_endian(assignment_type b) {
        assignment_type rv = (b & 0xFF) >> 8; 
        rv |= (b & 0xFF00) << 8;
        return rv;
    }
};


template<class B, size_t start, size_t end>
struct BitSlice {
    static constexpr size_t length = end - start + 1;
    using assignment_type = 
        typename BitSliceTraits<length>::assignment_type;
    using ref_type = typename B::container_type;

    inline explicit BitSlice(B& bf) noexcept : ref(bf.data())  {}

    inline BitSlice& operator= (assignment_type arg) noexcept {
        arg = BitSliceTraits<length>::little_endian(arg);

        for (size_t i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
            ref[i] = (arg & (1 << (i - start))) != 0 ? true : false;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    inline operator assignment_type () const noexcept {
        assignment_type rv(0);
        for (size_t i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
            rv |= (assignment_type(ref[i]) << (i - start));
        }
        return rv;
    }

    ref_type& ref;
}; 

template<typename B>
struct BitFieldView {
    using bitfield_type = B;
};

struct FooView : public BitFieldView<BitField<unsigned short>> {
    using bft = bitfield_type;
    inline explicit FooView (bft& bf) noexcept : a(bf), b(bf), c(bf) {}
    BitSlice<bft,  0, 11> a; // 12    
    BitSlice<bft, 12, 12> b; // 1
    BitSlice<bft, 13, 15> c; // 3
};

struct BarView : public BitFieldView<BitField<unsigned short>> {
    using bft = bitfield_type;
    inline explicit BarView (bft& bf) noexcept : a(bf), b(bf), c(bf), d(bf) {}
    BitSlice<bft,  0,  3> a; //4    
    BitSlice<bft,  4,  7> b; //4
    BitSlice<bft,  8, 11> c; //4
    BitSlice<bft, 12, 15> d; //4    
};



std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, uint8_t val) {
    return os << std::hex << ulong(val);
}


int main(){
    //   BIOS   FOOD
    //  0xB105 0xF00D 
    {
        BitField<unsigned short> bf = 0x0; 

        // 0xB105 = 1011 0001 0000 0101 = 101 1 000100000101;
        FooView(bf).a = 0b000100000101;
        FooView(bf).b = 1;
        FooView(bf).c = 0b101;

        std::cout << std::hex << bf.to_ullong() << ' '; 
    }
    {
                                        // 0xF00D
        BitField<unsigned short> bf = 0b1111000000001101;

        std::cout << BarView(bf).d 
                  << BarView(bf).c 
                  << BarView(bf).b 
                  << BarView(bf).a 
                  << std::endl; 
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e16b59f40019183) at Coliru's**

output:

```
b105 f00d
```